# Open Source ASP.NET Controls Library

Tags: asp.net, open-source, web-controls

We are looking for a ASP.NET Rich Controls Library. We don't have much budget to spend. We are looking for a decent choice which give a rich feeling to our application, works and reliable.

What are the best available options on ASP.NET Controls Library which are free and has good support online?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI free and good support online are usually antonyms IMO the cost of a control set from a company is nearly an unbeatable value for the price especially when they include support because you will always inevitably have issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [ASP.NET Ajax control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/) yet?

Comment: @Robert yes but we are looking for more rich controls like telerik

Comment: I believe he meant more of a control set similar to Telerik's or DevExpress's premium lines.

Comment: They do not exist AFAIK.  Telerik is the gold standard, IMO.

Comment: I found some good rich controls which are cheap ... visualwebgui.com and obout.com. visualwebgui is open source.

Comment: @Ramiz: Visual Webgui is something different. It is the Gizmox platform that attempts to emulate winforms and VB6 in a web browser. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: If you want to redistribute the controls in an application, the license for `obout` is $700+. You might as well go with Telerik.

Comment: This is the simplest definition of Visual WebGUI. Thanks @Robert.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a boatload of controls here that are open source:

http://sourceforge.net/

Hard to just give you a library wihtout knowing your requirements.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't say google.com :)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? It is a huge site where should I locate them?